# Como escribir en 2 input simultaneamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Me surge la siguiente duda,

Tengo un formulario en el que el usuario tiene que rellenar varias veces la misma información, por lo tanto quiero añadir la funcionalidad de que marcando un check se rellenen X campos en todos los input (por ejemplo el nombre, que es común)

¿Sabéis si existe alguna funcionalidad propia de angular para esto?

Comment: Yo lo que tengo visto por la web es que, al hacer check, los campos duplicados simplemente se ocultan de forma que el usuario ya no tenga que rellenarlos. Por ejemplo, si recuerdo correctamente, en Amazon cuando pones la dirección de envío tienes un check para avisar de que la dirección de facturación es la misma y toda la sección de dirección de facturación queda oculta.

Comment: Si, también podría copiar esa configuración, el problema es que, normalmente, los usuarios que usen el portal no van a ser nada expertos, es decir, hay que facilitarles la vida lo máximo para que lo usen.

Comment: Juega con el valor de los modales en el html desde el controlador. Cuando empiece a escribir en un campo común crea una función que evalúe si el check está activado. Si lo está que vaya igualando el valor de los modals de los otros input al que está rellenando.

Answer (score 6):

creo que la solución para lo que preguntas es controlar la entrada de la primera caja con el valor original y luego, en función del valor del check, transladarlo. Te he preparado un pequeño ejemplo que creo que hace lo que pides.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.oneinput = "hola";
  $scope.writevalue = function() {
        if($scope.oneinput==true) {
          $scope.box2 = $scope.box1;
        }
      };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<div>
  Caja1: <input type="text" ng-model="box1" ng-change="writevalue()">
  Repetir: <input type="checkbox" id="check" ng-model="oneinput" ng-init="false">
  </div>
  <div>
    Caja2: <input type="text" ng-model="box2">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo

Comment: A esto es básicamente a lo que me refería en mi comentario de arriba, si.

Comment: La verdad que es justo lo que buscaba, lo único sería el que se borrase el segundo input al quitar el check de repetir, pero ya investigo.